# Cannot resolve method io()

Tags: android, rx-java2, rx-android

I am still new with this RxAndroid And Rxjava and I got this error on `.subscribeOn(Scheduler.io())`

```html
 private void fetchData() {
        compositeDisposable.add(iPokemonDex.getListPokemon()
        .subscribeOn(Scheduler.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<Pokedex>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Pokedex pokedex) throws Exception {

                    }
                })
        );
    }
```

Comment: Scheduler -> Schedulers.io()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `Schedulers.io` with an `s`. So your code should be like this:

```
compositeDisposable.add(iPokemonDex.getListPokemon()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<Pokedex>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Pokedex pokedex) throws Exception {

                    }
                })
        );
```